# Redirect ends up outside of application

Tags: azure, redirect, asp.net-core

I am working on a .Net Core web application and we would like to be able to redirect a type of url to our custom error page. The site is hosted on Azure and it seems that this error is not being handled in the application. Here is the type of URL I am working with:

```
www.mywebsite.com/%22http://www.yahoo.com/%22
```

The error page that is presented is the following:

```
The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.
```

In addition when I check the live HTTP traffic on Azure it does not show an error occurring.

Edit: 
Apparently azure cannot handle this type request at all: https://azure.microsoft.com/%22/http://www.google.com/

It looks for the config file within the second url. Does anyone know where I can file a bug with Microsoft?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this on Azure, however it works on our server.

Configure exceptions handling in `Startup` class.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    // ...
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/error");
    }
    // ...
    app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/error/{0}");
    // ...
}
```

And error controller.

```
[Route("[controller]")]
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    [Route("")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [Route("{httpStatusCode}")]
    public IActionResult Index(int httpStatusCode)
    {
        // handle by error code
        switch (httpStatusCode)
        {
            case (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound:
                return View("NotFound");
            default:
                return View();
        }
    }
}
```